# Pass data from Activity to class

Tags: android

I'm trying to change Roman's Nurik [WizardPager](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager/) so that in one of the steps display some data from my database.
I'm taking a Model and an UI from the library and I modify them so I can have a 
DisplayOrderPage with a parameter ArrayList for my data

```
public DisplayOrderPage(ModelCallbacks callbacks, ArrayList<Salads>  ord ,  String title) {
    super(callbacks, ord, title);
}
```

and a `DisplayOrderFragment` which is going to display the data.

I can get an ArrayList with my data from my database in the MainActivity **but** I don't know how to pass that data to the [SandwichWizardModel](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager/blob/master/src/com/example/android/wizardpager/SandwichWizardModel.java) since it's not an Activity.

Comment: If I am not wrong then you want to change the gui from another class by passing an Arraylist as a parameter. is it?

Comment: @StinePike yes, pretty much. Thinking of a new constructor with the ArrayList as a param ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing.. also pass the context of the activity as parameter. And declare a method in the activity which change the gui within a handler .. like this

in Activity

```
changeGUI(){
   new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
       // change gui 
   }
}
```

and call like

```
methodInCLasse(this, arrayList);
```